# Can I block PR created by me from merge on the git?

Tags: git, github

I am working on several features, where feature N+1 is depends on the feature N. And I want to achieve clean diff for each pull request, and to create PRs one by one. This not a big task, this is just several bugs, but to run the app I need in N+1 the previous fixes.

So I am following next workflow:

1. Create `bugfix/bug1` from the `dev`
2. Fix, create PR `bugfix/bug1`=>`dev`
3. Create `bugfix/bug2` from the `bugfix/bug1` as I need fixes from the first one
4. Fix, create PR `bugfix/bug2` => `bugfix/bug1` to see clean diff

Later once all the PRs would be checked, I will merge `bugfix/bug1` to `dev`, then update the destination `bugfix/bug2` from `bugfix/bug1` to `dev` and merge it also to the `dev`.

The issue that `N + 1` is including all the changes from previous would be handled by `rebase` if necessary.

I would like to make it impossible to merge `N+1` to `N` accidently. Currently the solution is to mark the PR's title with prefix `(WFM #{PR number})` as a reminder. Maybe this scenario can be handled by `github` itself in some way?

The `github.com` is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a "non mergeable" PR on github : you can mark it as draft

Links to github's doc :

- [Draft pull requests](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests#draft-pull-requests)
- for new PRs : step 6 of [Creating the pull request](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request#creating-the-pull-request) - drop down menu of the "Create pull request" button
- for existing PRs: [Converting a pull request to a draft](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/changing-the-stage-of-a-pull-request#converting-a-pull-request-to-a-draft)

Comment: Don't forget to check in docs for what repos the feature is available. https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Draft-Pull-Requests-not-available/td-p/19139